# Bootstrap responsive embed disappears when inside flexbox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am using the flexbox to center align the items inside (as nothing else seems to work). Although the bootstrap responsive-embed seems to completely disappear and i have no idea why. I can't not use `position: relative` on the embed as this stop it being responsive. Here is the code for it...

```css
.embed-responsive {
  /*position: initial;*/ /* if set to initial or anything other than relative is re-appears but is no longer responsive */
}

body {
  background: grey;
}

div.title-area {
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

div.title-area .video {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

div.title-area > .col-md-6 {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

div.title-area h1 {
    text-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /*vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;*/
}

.title-area h1 > small{
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-indent: 5px;
    display: block;
    opacity: .6;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="title-area">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>main title<small>subtitle</small></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rqEy5_W6YHQ?showinfo=0"></iframe>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shixma/qt16k5yh/)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look to [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) you may insert your "col-md-6" inside two rows like in the following snipppet:

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

div.title-area {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

div.title-area .video {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

div.title-area > .col-md-6 {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div.title-area h1 {
  text-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /*vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;*/
}

.title-area h1 > small{
  color: gray;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  display: block;
  opacity: .6;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="title-area">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>main title<small>subtitle</small></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rqEy5_W6YHQ?showinfo=0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is correct always it needs to wrap .col divs with .row div to make it work correctly

Comment: Putting them in rows makes them stack no matter the resolution, what im looking to do is have the 2 columns to be side by side.

Comment: @Shixma You may use only one row and col-xs instead of col-md

Answer (score 0):

Add a div around the embed-responsive div so that the former can flow in the flex div and the latter can have position relative needed by the embed-responsive-item. Give the new div a flex-grow style of 1 so it sizes.

HTML:

```
<div class="title-area">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h1>main title<small>subtitle</small></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rqEy5_W6YHQ?showinfo=0"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.embed-responsive {
  // position: initial;
  /* if set to initial or anything other than relative is re-appears but is no longer responsive */
}

body {
  background: grey;
}

div.title-area {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

div.title-area .video {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

div.title-area > .col-md-6 {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div.title-area h1 {
  text-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /*vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;*/
}

.title-area h1 > small {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  display: block;
  opacity: .6;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rz5cmpz3/2/

Comment: While this does kind of work, unfortunately this stops it from preserving its aspect ratio.

Comment: @Shixma I've edited it to preserve the aspect ratio.